# phpOIDC Providers list

Tags: php, openid

I am trying to run phpOIDC. Here is the phpOIDC bitbucket link https://bitbucket.org/PEOFIAMP/phpoidc

I followed all the setup instructions. Now when I run my localhost/phpRp. It displays me a page whose screenshot is [image]

But there is no list for OP in the select menu. While going through the index.php code, it calls a function db_get_providers which shoud provide it a identity provider list from the database. But since the table in the database is empty and there are no instructions on how to fill up the table. I am having troubles to run this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to input the email address of the provider who supports Webfinger. 
Otherwise, you need to manually input the OP's https URI into the box.

For example, you can input alice@connect.openid4.us in "Or Enter OP URL" text box. 
Then, it performs the discovery and you are taken to the OP. 
Otherwise, you input like: "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration".

Once it proves to be successful, they are going to be recorded in the DB so that it will appear in the pull down.

NOTE: You typically need to register your client before performing these. 
Not many providers provides Dynamic Registration, thus it has to be done manually.

Nat